# loading a local woff2 file in a CSS file isn't working

Tags: html, css, web, fonts

I'm trying to load a woff2 font file within a CSS file. But I keep getting an error saying that the file can't be found. But the path is correct.

**My CSS file:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("C:\Users\win10\Desktop\Electron_Projects\EnderFramework\_themes\_default\fonts\material_icons.woff2") format('woff2');
}

icon, icons{
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

**And this is the error that I keep getting:**

*Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/Userswin10%C3%9Esktop%0Electron_Projects%0EnderFramework_themes_default%0Fontsmaterial_icons.woff2:1*

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify an incomplete file path, relative.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("..\fonts\material_icons.woff2") format('woff2');
}
```

Also, an error may be caused due to the use of backslash.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../fonts/material_icons.woff2") format('woff2');
}
```

Comment: In my case, I must use the full path form. So that won't help me.

Comment: @enderadel 
Have you tried "flipping" the slash?

`src: url("C:/Users/win10/Desktop/Electron_Projects/EnderFramework/_themes/_default/fonts/material_icons.woff2") format('woff2');`